# How to use AJAX to populate state list depending on Country list?

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu

I have the code below that will change a state dropdown list when you change the country list.
How can I make it change the state list ONLY when country ID number 234 and 224 are selected?
If another country is selected it should be change into this text input box

```
<input type="text" name="othstate" value="" class="textBox">
```

**The form**

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
<option>Select Country</option>
<option value="223">USA</option>
<option value="224">Canada</option>
<option value="225">England</option>
<option value="226">Ireland</option>
</select>

<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="state">
<option>Select Country First</option>
</select>
```

**The javascript**

```
<script>
function getState(countryId)
{
   var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
   var req = getXMLHTTP();
   if (req)
   {
     req.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if (req.readyState == 4)
      {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200)
         {
        document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
     } else {
       alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
       }
      }
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check the countryId value before you do the AJAX request and only perform the request if the countryId is in the allowable range.  In the case where the countryId doesn't match, I would hide the select (probably clear it's value, too) and show an already existing input that was previously hidden.  The reverse should be done if an allowable country is chosen.

jQuery example below:

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
   <select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)">
      <option>Select Country</option>
      <option value="223">USA</option>
      <option value="224">Canada</option>
      <option value="225">England</option>
      <option value="226">Ireland</option>
   </select>

   <select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="state">
      <option>Select Country First</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="othstate" value="" class="textBox" style="display: none;">
</form>

$(function() {
    $('#country').change( function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == 223 || val == 224) {
            $('#othstate').val('').hide();
            $.ajax({
               url: 'findState.php',
               dataType: 'html',
               data: { country : val },
               success: function(data) {
                   $('#state').html( data );
               }
            });
        }
        else {
           $('#state').val('').hide();
           $('#othstate').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I follow the theory I just don't know enough javascript to write it, im a php man

Comment: You're better off using jQuery anyway.  I've added a jQuery example.

Comment: I like this as I already have jquery loaded on all pages,
The example code gives me this error $ is not defined

Comment: Another though instead of loading a new page with states, if I were to  have the states list already on the page could it be hidden and then shown in the same manner?

Comment: Yes.  If the states were already on the page, you could show/hide those although that would get tricky if you expanded to more than two countries with states.  You'd also have to be careful how you named them or change the names when making them visible/invisible.

Comment: You'd need to include this code **after** loading jQuery.  If not, you'll get the '$ is not defined error.'  getState was your function.  You probably left the reference to it in your HTML and it is no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple thing to do is to provide a state dropdown and a text entry box with different ids. Set the display of both to **none** and then you just need to surround your contents of getState() with

```
if (countryId == 233 || countryId == 234) {
   /* Ajax state population here */

   dropdownId.display = 'block';
   textEntryId.display = 'none';
}
else  {
   textEntryId.display = 'block';
   dropdownId.display = 'none';
}
```

(where `dropdownId` and `textEntryId` are the ids of the relevant UI components) so you enable/display the display for the state dropdown or the text entry upon selection.

JQuery is all well and good, but I wouldn't introduce it *just* to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: here is a solution that works quite well for the task, adapting the lines of Tvanfosson:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#country').change( function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == 223 || val == 224) {
        $('#othstate').val('').hide();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'findState.php',
           dataType: 'html',
           data: { country : val },
           success: function(data) {
               $('#state').html( data );
           }
        });
    }
    else {
       $('#state').val('').hide();
       $('#othstate').show();
    }
  });
});
</script>

<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" id=country >
  <option>Select Country</option>
  <option value="223">USA</option>
  <option value="224">Canada</option>
  <option value="225">England</option>
  <option value="226">Ireland</option>
</select>

<select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="state">
  <option>Select Country First</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="othstate" id=othstate value="" class="textBox" style="display: none;">
```

As you can see, I eliminated the `<form>` element which is not absolutely necessary but can be added (and then has to be used properly in case JS is deactivated at the users end. See 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704753/is-form-tag-necessary-in-ajax-web-application).

I also eliminated the `onchange` event which is being replaced by the 'change()` jquery function.

Answer (score 1):

```
**index.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Populate City Dropdown Using jQuery Ajax</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxServer.jsp",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
select { width: 10em }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <label>Country:</label></td>
            <td>    <select class="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td >
        <label>States:</label></td>
     <td>   <select id="response">
                    <option>Select State</option>

                </select>
        </td></tr>

    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>

**ajaxServer.jsp**
<option>Select State</option>
<% 
String count=request.getParameter("country");
String india[]={"Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"};
String usa[]={"New Yourk", "Los Angeles","California"};
String uk[]={"London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"};
String states[];
if(count.equals("india"))
{
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
    out.print("<option>"+india[i]+"</option>");
    }
}
else if(count.equals("usa"))
{
    for(int i=0;i<usa.length;i++)
    {
    out.print("<option>"+usa[i]+"</option>");
    }
}
else if(count.equals("uk"))
{
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
    out.print("<option>"+uk[i]+"</option>");
    }
}

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

VK API just select country , get it id and select city from

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var _getCountry = function() {
    $j.ajax({
      url: "http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries",
      data: {
       'v': 5.5,
        'need_all': 0,
        'code' : 'RU,UA,BY,KZ,KG,LV,EE'  
       // 'count': 10
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data, status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
          return false;
        }
        console.log(data.response, status); 
          
        $j.each(data.response.items, function(i, item) {
         console.log("each country");
         var newOption = '<option id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.title + '">' + item.title + '</option>';
         country_options.push(newOption);
       });
    
       document.getElementById('countrylist').innerHTML = country_options;
          
      }
        
 });  
 }   

var _getCity = function(country_id) {
     
    $j.ajax({
      url: "http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCities",
      data: {
       'v': 5.61,
        'need_all': 0,
        'country_id': country_id
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data, status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
          return false;
        }
        console.log(data.response, status); 
          
        $j.each(data.response.items, function(i, item) {
         console.log("each city");
         var newOption = '<option id="' + item.id + '" value="' + item.title + '">' + item.title + '</option>';
         city_options.push(newOption);
       });
    
       document.getElementById('citylist').innerHTML = city_options;
          
      }
        
 });  
 }  
       
var  city_options = [];
var  country_options = [];
    
 $j(document).ready(function () {  
    _getCountry(); 
     
  $j('#country').on('input',function() {
    var opt = $j('option[value="'+$j(this).val()+'"]');
    var countryid = opt.attr('id');  
      
    _getCity(countryid);  
      
     
  });

  
 });

</script>
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Страна:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
          
              <div class="controls">
             <input name="country" list="countrylist" id="country" class="form-control" />
                <datalist id="countrylist">
                </datalist> 
              </div>
        
           
           
            
          </div>
        </div> 
   
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Город:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
                
            <input name="city" list="citylist" id="city" class="form-control"/>
                <datalist id="citylist">
            </datalist>  
              
           
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
////////////////// connection file con.php rishabh
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
         $dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }
         mysql_select_db( 'testajax' );
?>

/////////////////////////// index.php rishabh
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<?php 
include('con.php');
?>
<form>
<div class="frmDronpDown">
    <div class="row">
        <table><tr><td><label>Country:</label><br/>
        <select name="country" id="country" data-name="country" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getCountry(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
         $sql = mysql_query("SELECT distinct country FROM statecont ");
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $result['country']; ?>"><?php echo $result['country']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select> </td>
             <td>
<label>Phone:</label><br/>
        <select name="phone" id="phone" data-name="phone" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getPhone(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
         $sql = mysql_query("SELECT distinct phone FROM statecont ");
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $result['phone']; ?>"><?php echo $result['phone']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select> 
</td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div id="state-list"></div>
</div>
</form>
<script>
function getCountry(val) {
        var dataname = $('#country').attr('data-name');

        console.log(dataname);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
        data: {
                value_name: val,
                colomn_name: dataname
                },
    success: function (data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}

function getPhone(val) {
        var dataname = $('#phone').attr('data-name');

    console.log(dataname);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
        data: {
                 value_name: val,
                colomn_name: dataname
                },
    success: function (data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>

// ////////////////////data file data.php rishabh
<?php 
$val = $_POST["value_name"]; 
$colomn = $_POST["colomn_name"]; 
include('con.php');
$sql_aa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statecont where ".$colomn."='$val'"); ?>
  <table>
<tr><td>State</td><td>Countery</td></tr>
<?php while($result_aa=mysql_fetch_array($sql_aa)){ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $result_aa['state']; ?></td><td><?php echo $result_aa['country']; ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Add comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Never to $sql_aa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statecont where ".$colomn."='$val'"); ?>

it is an open door to SQL injectin .

Comment: How can this be related to the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).