# How to change the state list dynalically according to the selected country in CS-Cart?

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I'm struggling with an issue in my CS-Cart register page, can anybody please help me out to fix this issue.

In the register form if an user selects a country then I want to refresh the states list according to the selected country, how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Exsting question , Please refer

[How to use AJAX to populate state list depending on Country list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185712/how-to-use-ajax-to-populate-state-list-depending-on-country-list)

Or Refer this

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: Thanks Yashwanth, I know how to handle this scenario using AJAX but my problem is with the CS-Cart. In CS-Cart register from country and state fields are dynamically generating by the cart, I want to know how to handle this scenario in CS-Cart.