# how can i get countries states list from states table ,when i select country from countries table using multiple selection dropdown?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

how to get countries states list from states table when i select country from countries table using multiple selection dropdown list ? here is my coding.

### mysql tables

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `countryID` varchar(3) NOT NULL default '',
  `countryName` varchar(52) NOT NULL default '',
  `localName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `webCode` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `continent` enum('Asia','Europe','North America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America') NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL default '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL default '0',
  `surfaceArea` float(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `population` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`countryID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `webCode` (`webCode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `countryName` (`countryName`),
  KEY `region` (`region`),
  KEY `continent` (`continent`),
  KEY `surfaceArea` (`surfaceArea`),
  KEY `population` (`population`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## Structure for the `states` table :

```
CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `stateID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `stateName` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `countryID` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL default '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`stateID`),
  KEY `stateName` (`stateName`),
  KEY `countryID` (`countryID`),
  KEY `unq` (`countryID`,`stateName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## Data for the `countries` table  (LIMIT 0,500)

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (`countryID`, `countryName`, `localName`, `webCode`, `region`, `continent`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `surfaceArea`, `population`) VALUES 
  ('BRA','Brazil','Brasil','BR','South America','South America',-10,-55,8547403.00,170115000),
  ('CHN','China','Zhongquo','CN','Eastern Asia','Asia',35,105,9572900.00,1277558000),
  ('FRA','France','France','FR','Western Europe','Europe',47,2,551500.00,59225700),
  ('IND','India','Bharat/India','IN','Southern and Central Asia','Asia',28.47,77.03,3287263.00,1013662000),
   ('USA','USA','United States','US','North America','North America',38,-97,9363520.00,278357000);
COMMIT;
```

## Data for the `states` table  (LIMIT 0,500)

```
INSERT INTO `states` (`stateID`, `stateName`, `countryID`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES 
  (5,'California','USA',37.42,-122.06),
  (6,'Beijing','CHN',39.93,116.39),
  (9,'Iowa','USA',43.03,-96.09),
  (10,'New York','USA',40.76,-73.97),
  (12,'... ....','CHN',32.06,118.78);
COMMIT;
```

### Countries dropdown

```
<? $Type_sql="SELECT countryName FROM countries ORDER by countryName ASC";
                                $Type_result=mysql_query($Type_sql);
                                while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){
                                echo "<option value='"; 
                                echo $Type_rows['countryName']; 
                                echo "'>";
                                echo $Type_rows['countryName'];
                                echo "</option>";
                                } ?>
            </select>
```

### states dropdown

```
<? $Type_sql="SELECT stateName FROM countries c, states s where c.countryID = s.countryID ORDER by stateName ASC";
                                $Type_result=mysql_query($Type_sql);
                                while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){
                                echo "<option value='"; 
                                echo $Type_rows['stateName']; 
                                echo "'>";
                                echo $Type_rows['stateName'];
                                echo "</option>";
                                } ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) It is easier to help you when you tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: i want make content change on states dropdown when selected a country from country dropdown.

Comment: "multiple selection dropdown list" where does that come from, is that a plugin for a javascript library like jQuery? Please be more extensive in explaining the issue instead of posting wall of code :P

Comment: also if i selected more than one country , i want see all that countries states list on states dropdown

Comment: You will need javascript and bind the `onchange` event of the countries dropdown to another js method that enables the states dropdown and populates it with the right states for the selected country. This can be with an ajax call to make the page load faster (due to not having to load all the states from all the countries)

Comment: This has been asked numerous times and answered even more times on SO

Comment: yes, it is a javascript. i need to make change "state " dropdown list according to the country i choose from country dropdown list

Comment: SO is not a website to bluntly fire questions. Please explain what you have tried so far. You already are aware you'll need javascript, but you are not referring to any javascript in your question. Please elaborate, show the links you're using as sources and create a more extensive question!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1185712/592540

Comment: Carlos Campderrós gave the exact answer for my question. but, can any one help me to make onchange events for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi Ahmed,**

*Please have a look at the below code.
I reworked the code and modified for multiple selections*
Anyway i have ignored the javascript validation. please work on that and name of this page was **form3.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function viewstates()
    { 
        jQuery('#langucountry').change(function () { });
    }
    $(function() {
        $('#basicmultiselect').multiSelect({select_all_min: 3});
        $('#langucountry').multiSelect({
            select_all_min: 3, no_selection: "Please select!", selected_text: " clicked" });
        $('#methods').multiSelect(); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form3" action="form3.php" method="post">
<?php
/****** connection string *******/
/* start */
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $dbSelect = mysql_select_db("test");
/* end */

/*----checks whether form is submited -------*/
if(isset($_POST['cbocountry']))
{
    $lstStates = array();
        foreach($_POST['cbocountry'] as $countryCode)
        {
            $fetch_states="SELECT stateName FROM  states where countryID = '$countryCode' ORDER by stateName ASC";
            $Type_result=mysql_query($fetch_states);
            while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){

                        if(!in_array($Type_rows['stateName'],$lstStates))
                            array_push($lstStates,$Type_rows['stateName']);
             } 
        }

}


                                $Type_sql="SELECT countryID,countryName FROM countries ORDER by countryName ASC";
                                $Type_result=mysql_query($Type_sql);
                                echo"Countries:<select  id=\"langucountry\" name=\"cbocountry[]\" class=\"arc90_multiselect\" multiple=\"multiple\" title=\"Languages\"\>";
                                while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){

                                        echo "<option value='".$Type_rows['countryID']."'>";
                                        echo $Type_rows['countryName'];
                                        echo "</option>";
                                } 
                                echo"</select>";





                    echo"States:<select><option value=''>--select--</option>";
                            if(count($lstStates) > 0)
                            {
                                foreach($lstStates as $item)
                                {
                                    echo "<option value='"; 
                                    echo $item; 
                                    echo "'>";
                                    echo $item;
                                    echo "</option>";
                                } 
                            }
                    echo"</select>";

                    echo"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" text=\"submit\"/>";

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Enjoy!!!!**

Comment: ok, but if it put two javascript link and make country list in checkbox style it doesn't work

Comment: these are javascript files. you can search and download .<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/arc90_multiselect.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by putting the code for the states dropdown into a separate php handler, a bit modified:

```
<select name="state">
<?php 
    $countryID= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['countryID']);
    $Type_sql="SELECT stateName FROM states s where s.countryID = '$countryID' ORDER by stateName ASC";
                $Type_result=mysql_query($Type_sql);
                while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){
                    echo "<option value='";
                    echo $Type_rows['stateName'];
                    echo "'>";
                    echo $Type_rows['stateName'];
                    echo "</option>";
                } 
?>
</select>
```

This script will be called by javascript using Ajax every time there is an onChange event in the countries select list. Please refer to ajax documentation like http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml or use jQuery for that: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Modifying the content of the state select like your plan is now is possible too, but then you'd need two select lists, one more hidden list to store your removed entries or just all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully working code.
Just place this code in a php page and change the name of the form in the onChange parameter to your page name.Also, change the database name in **mysql_select_db**.

My page name was *form1.php*

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['stateId']))
{
    $stateId = $_REQUEST['stateId'];
}
else
{
    $stateId = "";
}
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$dbSelect = mysql_select_db("test");
$Type_sql="SELECT countryID,countryName FROM countries ORDER by countryName ASC";
                                $Type_result=mysql_query($Type_sql);
                                echo"Countries:<select onChange=\"window.location='form1.php?stateId='+this.value\">";
                                while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){
                                    if($Type_rows['countryID']==$_REQUEST['stateId'])
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value='".$Type_rows['countryID']."' selected>";
                                        echo $Type_rows['countryName'];
                                        echo "</option>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value='".$Type_rows['countryID']."'>";
                                        echo $Type_rows['countryName'];
                                        echo "</option>";
                                    }
                                } 
                                echo"</select>";

 $Type_sql="SELECT stateName FROM  states where countryID = '$stateId' ORDER by stateName ASC";
                                $Type_result=mysql_query($Type_sql);
                    echo"States:<select><option value=''>--select--</option>";
                                while($Type_rows=mysql_fetch_array($Type_result)){
                                echo "<option value='"; 
                                echo $Type_rows['stateName']; 
                                echo "'>";
                                echo $Type_rows['stateName'];
                                echo "</option>";
                                } 
                    echo"</select>";

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, it is ok, but i want "multiple selected dropdopwn" to make work like that. and if i selected more than one country i need all that countries "state" to be loaded on state dropdown (this is also multiple selected dropdown).

Comment: this what i used to make multiple dropdown          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/arc90_multiselect.js"></script>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function viewstates(){
jQuery('#langucountry').change(function () {


});
}
  </script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
            $('#basicmultiselect').multiSelect({select_all_min: 3});
            $('#langucountry').multiSelect({

Comment: select_all_min: 3,
                                no_selection: "Please select!",
                                selected_text: " clicked"
                               });
            $('#methods').multiSelect();
  });
  </script>

Comment: and for country dropdown <select id="langucountry" name="cbocountry[]" class="arc90_multiselect" multiple="multiple" title="Languages" onChange="window.location='form1.php?stateId='+this.value\"></select>