# Merge two forms into one Form Handler

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I need a "Contact" form with "Business Name", "Contact Name", and "Email" to display when the page is loaded. Then, after the user adds input and hits "Add More", the form will expand to include the fields from a separate "Quote" form AND an email will be sent to me with the information from the "Contact" form.

Then, after the user adds input to the fields in the "Quote" form, I need the information from both of those forms to be submitted and handled by the page POSTing to itself, while sending and email to me with the combined information from the "Contact" and "Quote" forms AND sending a thank you email to the user.

If there were any errors, a 3rd "Quote Form Handler" which includes the fields from both forms would be re-displayed, maintaining the valid input from the "Contact" and "Quote" forms and showing which fields are required.

Is this possible? How would I go about it?

I have tried using AJAX. I've tried to setTimeout.

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<style>
/* BEGIN CSS RESET */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        }
        ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
        }
        img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        }
/*END CSS RESET*/   

/* BEGIN FORM */
    .form-embed {
        padding: 24px;
        background: grey;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }

    label {
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#00ccff;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    input, select {
        height: 48px;
        width: 100%;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
        display: block;
        -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    input:hover {
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    }

    input[type=button], input[type=submit]{
      background-color: #1E90FF;
      border: none;
      width: 25%;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      display:inline-block;
    }

    .buttons {
     text-align: center;
    }

    .bodyText {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

#Contact_Form{
    width: 100%;
}

.hiddenForm {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.error {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* END FORM */

</style>
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formButton").click(function(){
        $(".hiddenForm").show();
        $("#Contact_Form").hide();
        $(".hide-button").hide();

        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        var post_url = $(this).attr("ajax.php"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("POST"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $('#Contact_Form').serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

        $.ajax({
            url : post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data
        }).done(function(response){ 
            $("#server-results").html(response);
        });
    });

    $("#submitButton").click(function(event){

        //$(".hiddenForm").show();
        //$("#Quote_Form").hide();
        //$("#Contact_Form").hide();
        $("#Quote_Form").submit();

        //$("#Contact_Form").submit();

        //setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("Contact_Form").submit();}, 3000);  
    });

    /*$("#submitButton").click(function(){
        $("#Contact_Form").submit();
        $("#Quote_Form").submit();
    });
    */



});

</script>

<div class="form-embed">
    <form id="Contact_Form" name="Contact_Form" target="_blank" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
        <div class="bodyText"><p style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="font-family: 'times new roman', 
            times; font-size: 18px; color: #00ccff;">
            <strong><span style="font-size: 24px;"><em>Looking For A Quote</em>
            </span>?&nbsp;</strong></span>
        </div>
        <br><br>    
        <label for="bizName" class="control-label">Business Name:</label>
        <input required maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Business Name" name="bizName" id="bizName"  />
        <label for="cName" class="control-label">Contact Name:</label>
        <input required maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact Name" name="cName" id="cName"  />
        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address: </label>
        <input required maxlength="200" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email" id="email"  />
        <br>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="hide-button">
            <input id="formButton" class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button" value="Add More" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>





    <div class="hiddenForm">
        <form id="Quote_Form" name="Quote_Form" target="_blank" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
            <div class="bodyText"><p style="text-align: center;">
                <span style="font-family: 'times new roman', 
                times; font-size: 18px; color: #00ccff;">
                <strong><span style="font-size: 24px;"><em>Looking For A Quote</em>
                </span>?&nbsp;</strong></span>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <label for="bizName" class="control-label">Business Name:</label>
            <input required maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $bizName; ?>" placeholder="Enter Business Name" name="bizName" id="bizName"  />
            <label for="cName" class="control-label">Contact Name:</label>
            <input required maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cName; ?>" placeholder="Enter Contact Name" name="cName" id="cName" />
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address: </label>
            <input required maxlength="200" type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email" id="email"  />
            <label for="bizType">Business Type: </label>
            <select name="bizType"> 
            <option value="">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
            <option value="Bar or Pub">Bar or Pub</option>
            <option value="Brewery">Brewery</option>
            <option value="Wedding Venue">Wedding Venue</option>
            <option value="Salon or Spa">Salon or Spa</option>
            <option value="Event or Party Space">Event or Party Space</option>
            <option value="Funeral Home">Funeral Home</option>
            <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
            <option value="Museum or Gallery">Museum or Gallery</option>
            <option value="Industrial Facility">Industrial Facility</option>
            <option value="Medical Facility">Medical Facility</option>
            <option value="Commercial Property">Commercial Property</option>
            <option value="Fitness Facility / Gym">Fitness Facility / Gym</option>
            <option value="Sports or Recreational Facility ">Sports or Recreational Facility </option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <label for="address1">Address Line 1: </label>
        <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"
         size="40" placeholder="Street and number, P.O. box, c/o">
        <label for="address2">Address Line 2: (Optional)</label>
        <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2"
         size="40" placeholder = "Apartment, suite, unit, building, floor, ect."> 
        <label for="city" class="control-label">City: </label>
        <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" name="city" id="city" />
        <label for="state">State: </label> 
        <select name="state">
            <option value="">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama (AL)</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska (AK)</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona (AZ)</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas (AR)</option>
            <option value="CA">California (CA)</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado (CO)</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut (CT)</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware (DE)</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia (DC)</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida (FL)</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia (GA)</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii (HI)</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho (ID)</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois (IL)</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana (IN)</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa (IA)</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas (KS)</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky (KY)</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana (LA)</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine (ME)</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland (MD)</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts (MA)</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan (MI)</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota (MN)</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi (MS)</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri (MO)</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana (MT)</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska (NE)</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada (NV)</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire (NH)</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey (NJ)</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico (NM)</option>
            <option value="NY">New York (NY)</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina (NC)</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota (ND)</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio (OH)</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma (OK)</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon (OR)</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania (PA)</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island (RI)</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina (SC)</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota (SD)</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee (TN)</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas (TX)</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah (UT)</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont (VT)</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia (VA)</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington (WA)</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia (WV)</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin (WI)</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming (WY)</option>
        </select>
        <label for="zip" class="control-label">Zip Code: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" size="5" 
        placeholder="Enter Zip Code" name="zip" id="zip" />
        <label for="sqft">Estimated Square Feet: </label>
        <select name="sqft">
            <option value="">Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="4,000 or less">4,000 sqft or less</option>
            <option value="5,000 to 9,000">5,000 sqft to 9,000 sqft</option>
            <option value="10,000 to 14,000">10,000 sqft to 14,000 sqft</option>
            <option value="15,000 to 20,000">15,000 sqft to 20,000 sqft</option>
            <option value="20,000 or more">20,000 sqft or more</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br>
            <div class="buttons">
                <!--<input id="submitButton" type="button" onclick="submitForms()" value="Submit the form"/>-->
                <input id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit the form" />
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php


$errorCount = "";

$bizNameErr = $bizTypeErr = $address1Err = $address2Err = $cityErr = $stateErr
= $zipErr = $sqftErr = $cNameErr = $emailErr = "";

$bizName = $bizType = $address1 = $address2 = $city = $state
= $zip = $sqft = $cName = $email = "";
// Check to make sure the required fields from the Quote Form are not empty
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["bizName"])) {
    $bizNameErr = "Business name is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $bizName = test_input($_POST["bizName"]);
  } 
  if (empty($_POST["cName"])) {
    $cNameErr = "Contact Name is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $cName = test_input($_POST["cName"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["bizType"])) {
    $bizTypeErr = "Business Type is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $bizType = test_input($_POST["bizType"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["address1"])) {
    $address1Err = "Address Line 1 is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $address1 = test_input($_POST["address1"]);
  }
   if (!empty($_POST["address2"])) {
    $address2 = test_input($_POST["address2"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "City is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["state"])) {
    $stateErr = "State is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["zip"])) {
    $zipErr = "Zip Code is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["sqft"])) {
    $sqftErr = "Square Feet is required";
    ++$errorCount;
  } else {
    $sqft = test_input($_POST["sqft"]);
  }   
}
// Form validation
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

// This function, when called, redisplays the Quote Form Handler
function redisplayForm($bizName, $bizType, $address1, $address2, $city, 
$state, $zip, $sqft, $cName, $email, $bizNameErr, $bizTypeErr,
$address1Err, $cityErr, $stateErr, $zipErr, $sqftErr, $cNameErr, $emailErr ) {
?>
<form name="Quote_Form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="form-embed">
        <span class="error"> <?php
// Determining that the user input was sent successfully and setting a resultMsg variable accordingly
        if (isset($result)) {
            $resultMsg = "Your infomation was sent successfully.";
        } else {
            $resultMsg = "There was a problem sending your information.";
        }
        echo $resultMsg; ?>
        </span><br><br>
        <p><span class="error">Please re-enter the information below. <br><br> * required field</span></p>
        <div class="bodyText"><p style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times; font-size: 18px; color: #00ccff;">
            <strong><span style="font-size: 24px;"><em>Looking For A Quote</em>
            </span>?&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
        </div><br><br>  
        <label for="bizName" class="control-label">Business Name:
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $bizNameErr;?> </span></label>
        <input required maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $bizName; ?>" placeholder="Enter Business Name" name="bizName" id="bizName"  />
        <label for="cName" class="control-label">Contact Name:
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $cNameErr;?></span></label>
        <input required maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cName; ?>" placeholder="Enter Contact Name" name="cName" id="cName" />
        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address: 
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></label>
        <input required maxlength="200" type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email" id="email"  />
        <label for="bizType" class="control-label">Business Type:
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $bizTypeErr;?></span></label>  
        <select required name="bizType">
            <?php 
                if(empty($_POST["bizType"])){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $bizType; ?>" disabled selected hidden><?php echo "Choose business type...";
                }
                else { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $bizType; ?>"><?php echo $bizType;?> </option><?php 
                } 
            ?>
            <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
            <option value="Bar or Pub">Bar or Pub</option>
            <option value="Brewery">Brewery</option>
            <option value="Wedding Venue">Wedding Venue</option>
            <option value="Salon or Spa">Salon or Spa</option>
            <option value="Event or Party Space">Event or Party Space</option>
            <option value="Funeral Home">Funeral Home</option>
            <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
            <option value="Museum or Gallery">Museum or Gallery</option>
            <option value="Industrial Facility">Industrial Facility</option>
            <option value="Medical Facility">Medical Facility</option>
            <option value="Commercial Property">Commercial Property</option>
            <option value="Fitness Facility / Gym">Fitness Facility / Gym</option>
            <option value="Sports or Recreational Facility ">Sports or Recreational Facility </option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <label for="address1" class="control-label">Address Line 1: 
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $address1Err;?></span></label>
        <input required type="text" name="address1" id="address1"
        size="40" value="<?php echo $address1; ?>" placeholder="Street and number, P.O. box, c/o">
        <label for="address2" class="control-label">Address Line 2:
        <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2"
        size="40" value="<?php echo $address2; ?>" placeholder = "Apartment, suite, unit, building, floor, ect."> 
        <label for="city" class="control-label">City:
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></span></label>
        <input required type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" placeholder="Enter City" name="city" id="city" />
        <label for="state" class="control-label">State:
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $stateErr;?></span></label>    
        <select required name="state">
            <?php 
                if(empty($_POST["state"])){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $state; ?>" disabled selected hidden><?php echo "Choose state...";
                }
                else { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $state; ?>"><?php echo $state;?> </option><?php 
                } 
            ?>
            <option value="AL">Alabama (AL)</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska (AK)</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona (AZ)</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas (AR)</option>
            <option value="CA">California (CA)</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado (CO)</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut (CT)</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware (DE)</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia (DC)</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida (FL)</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia (GA)</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii (HI)</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho (ID)</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois (IL)</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana (IN)</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa (IA)</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas (KS)</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky (KY)</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana (LA)</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine (ME)</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland (MD)</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts (MA)</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan (MI)</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota (MN)</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi (MS)</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri (MO)</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana (MT)</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska (NE)</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada (NV)</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire (NH)</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey (NJ)</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico (NM)</option>
            <option value="NY">New York (NY)</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina (NC)</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota (ND)</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio (OH)</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma (OK)</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon (OR)</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania (PA)</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island (RI)</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina (SC)</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota (SD)</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee (TN)</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas (TX)</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah (UT)</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont (VT)</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia (VA)</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington (WA)</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia (WV)</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin (WI)</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming (WY)</option>
        </select>
        <label for="zip" class="control-label">Zip Code:
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $zipErr;?></span></label>
        <input required type="text" class="form-control" 
        pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" size="5" 
        value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" name="zip" id="zip" />
        <label for="sqft" class="control-label">Estimated Square Feet: 
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $sqftErr;?></span></label>
        <select required name="sqft" >
            <?php 
                if(empty($_POST["sqft"])){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $sqft; ?>" disabled selected hidden><?php echo "Choose square footage...";
                }
                else { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $sqft; ?>"><?php echo $sqft;?> </option><?php 
                } 
            ?>
            <option value="4,000 or less">4,000 sqft or less</option>
            <option value="5,000 to 9,000">5,000 sqft to 9,000 sqft</option>
            <option value="10,000 to 14,000">10,000 sqft to 14,000 sqft</option>
            <option value="15,000 to 20,000">15,000 sqft to 20,000 sqft</option>
            <option value="20,000 or more">20,000 sqft or more</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div class="buttons">
            <!--<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Form"  /> -->
            <input id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit the form" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
}

// Error checking. If there are errors, call the redisplayForm function to redisplay the Quote Form Handler.
if ($errorCount>0 || $errorCount<0) {
    redisplayForm($bizName, $bizType, $address1, $address2, $city, 
    $state, $zip, $sqft, $cName, $email, $bizNameErr, $bizTypeErr,
    $address1Err, $cityErr, $stateErr, $zipErr, $sqftErr, $cNameErr, $emailErr );

    $bizNameErr = $bizTypeErr = $address1Err = $address2Err = $cityErr = $stateErr
    = $zipErr = $sqftErr = $cNameErr = $emailErr = "";

    $bizName = $bizType = $address1 = $address2 = $city = $state
    = $zip = $sqft = $cName = $email = "";
// If there are no errors, an email will be sent to Conversion Worx with the user's input.
} else {
    $To = "myemail"; 
    $Subject = "Quote Form Results";
    $Message = "Business Name: " . $bizName . "\n" 
    . "Business Type: " . $bizType . "\n"
    . "Address Line 1: " . $address1 . "\n"
    . "Address Line 2: " . $address2 . "\n"
    . "City: " . $city . "\n"
    . "State: " . $state . "\n"
    . "Zip Code: " . $zip . "\n"
    . "Estimated Square Feet: " . $sqft . "\n"
    . "Contact Name: " . $cName . "\n"
    . "Email Address: " . $email;
    $result = mail($To, $Subject, $Message);
}
// If email to Conversion Worx is sent succesfully, send thank you email to user.
if (isset($result)) {
    $To = $email;
    $Subject = "Virtual Tour Quote Request";
    $Headers = 'From: myemail' . "\r\n" . 
        'Reply-To: myemail' . "\r\n" . 
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $Message = $cName . ",";
    $Message .= "\n" . "\n" . "Thank you for your interest in our 3D 360° Virtual Tours!";
    $Message .= "\n" . "\n" . "Your information has been submitted. ";
    $Message .= "A Conversion Worx represenative will be contacting you shortly to arrange a quote via phone or on-site visit.";
    $Message .= "\n" . "\n" . "We look forward to working with you! ";
    $Message .= "\n" . "\n" . "\n" . "Sincerely,";
    $Message .= "\n" . "\n" . "The Conversion Worx Team";
    $result = mail($To, $Subject, $Message, $Headers);



}
 ?>
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: If it helps, I would love to show someone all of my code.

Comment: With some GET vars as flags to know when and what to send by mail and having the page as an PHP file, you can do this with or without the ajax technique (probably easier with no ajax). Try again. If you can't solve yourself, I will provide a generic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you know what you're doing code-wise, so I'll give you the overview.

First, there is no need to use the `<form>` constructs - you can do all this with DIVs (and inputs, buttons, etc) and AJAX.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293375/ajax-vs-form-submission/54757176#54757176) for more.

Next, you can use javascript/jQuery to present DIV structures that contain different bits of information to the user. Present the data to the user and use css `height:150vh;overflow:hidden;` along with a More button, like this:

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('#sam').removeClass('shrunk');
    $('#mybutt').hide();
    $('#nxtbutt').show();
});
```

```css
*{position:relative;}
div{margin:50px;width:350px;border:1px solid orange;background:bisque;}



.shrunk{height:120px;overflow:hidden;}
#nxtbutt{position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bob">
    <p id="sam" class="shrunk">Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. Here is a lot of text. </p>
    <button id="mybutt">More</button>
    <button id="nxtbutt">Next</button>
</div>
```

Then, when user clicks `nxtbutt` you can hide that DIV, and perhaps fade-in another one:

```
$('#nxtbutt').click(function(){
    $('#bob').fadeOut();
    $('#george').fadeIn();
});
```

When user has clicked the last button... you can collect all the info and ajax it to the PHP side. On the PHP side, do what you need to do and return some data to the DOM just by using PHP's `echo()` statement.

The data coming back from PHP will be received in the `.done()` function - and remember, that's a function so you might have scope issues accessing other variables. So, you can use little hacks like saving data into hidden input fields if needed:

```
.done(function(recd){
    $('body').append('<input id="gollee" type="hidden" value="' +recd+ '" />');
});
```

You can also have hidden divs that can act like buttons, and you can use those to trigger other events:

```
.done(function(recd){
    if(recd == "peter"){
        $('#gollee').val('dosummmat');
        $('#hiddenDIV3').click();
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '#hiddenDIV3', function(){
    let tmp = $('#gollee').val();
    alert(tmp);
});
```

---

References:

[AJAX and Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293375/ajax-vs-form-submission/54757176#54757176)

[More on AJAX and Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748657/how-to-validate-textarea-and-radio-button-in-a-loop/37749756#37749756)

Comment: I'm confused as to how to collect all the data from both forms and AJAX that to the PHP side.

Comment: Don't get confuzzled by having multiple data input regions. First, forget about forms - they are 1990 tech and they introduce walls and behaviors you don't need these days. Imagine 3 DIV structures. Each has several input fields (radio buttons, selects, etc). When user clicks a button where you want to send some data to a back-end PHP file and get an answer back, at that point (1) detect that button click (2) collect the user-inputted data (usually `.val()` of each element you want to send, and then [construct an AJAX block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26028031/1447509) to exchg info with PHP.

Comment: Did you briefly read the articles I posted as references? If not, give each one a quick review. I'm here if you have further questions.

Comment: @jimloomis4 Looking at your code/question, perhaps you are a little overwhelmed with the entire codebase. So, break it up! Create a second document (`test.html`?) and just solve one part of the problem -- Don't worry about appearance, css, etc - just solve the js-to-php-to-js functionality, one step at a time. It may sound like extra steps, but believe me, you could save hours. *(And as you solve each piece, a heavy load will lift off your shoulders...)*

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I looked at the links that you suggested. You are right, I am getting a bit overwhelmed working with everything at once. I'll definitely try making a test page.

I've made it so the first "Contact" form(div, when I change it) hides when the "add more" button is clicked. This then displays the hidden "Quote_Form", which includes the fields from the "Contact" form and some new fields. The problem now is that the "Quote_Form" isn't showing the input from the "Contact" form when it is displayed after clicking "add more". I'm getting "undefined variable" errors.

Comment: @jimloomis4 I have a couple of thoughts on the problem you are having... The error is telling the truth - it cannot find your variable. So, probably a scope problem. Two quick solutions: (a) When user clicks the `Add More` button, you might need to programmatically read the values from the fields they just completed: `var bob = $('#unique_id_of_field').val();` and programmatically schlep that value into the similar field in the Quote form: `$('#related_id_in_quote_form').val(bob);` Remember that all IDs must be **unique**, so name them well: e.g. `id="cont_fname"` and `"id=quot_fname"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477158/further-to-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-55402831-merge-two-forms-into-on

Comment: Jim, what about this idea: instead of having two forms, have only one form with a portion of the form hidden (perhaps wrapped in a div to group it all together). Then, when click the Add More button, two things happen: (1) the hidden group is revealed and (2) the same javascript routine collects the information from the already-filled-out fields and sends an ajax request (with that data) to a back-end PHP file that sends you the desired email. I also note that you are submitting your form to the same file - that works, but given your desired design, it will cause some headaches to get working

Comment: I am baffled by the downvotes / speedy closing of other ques, but that happens to all of us. Don't give up - some of it is "luck of the draw". Try to ascertain what caused the knee-jerk-downvoting and adjust your next question accordingly. I rather suspect part of the problem was the amount of code posted that made the question difficult to quickly parse. SO members generally prefer brief, concise, "what is wrong with this specific bit of code" questions as opposed to more generalized design-related questions. Bear in mind that **None** of the downvotes are personal - so modify and repost!

Comment: Note: I still get questions downvoted and immediately closed just as happened to you - that is the democratic nature of SO. Not everyone who has been given the downvote privilege has the maturity to self-manage that responsibility. But on the whole, the site works and is useful. Don't give up!

Comment: I edited the 2nd question I posted, but I'm not sure if anyone can see it now or not. I think it's closed?