# How do I add values to a dependent dropdown list in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two columns in my database: `faculty` and `department`. I managed to bind the data to a drop-down containing my `faculties`. But for a `department` which has a `foreign key` to `faculty`, how do I add a new one and display it in a drop-down as well?

Basically, I need that when I select a `faculty` from the first drop-down, `departments` for that specific `faculty` will be shown in the second drop-down, and I can add another department to the selected faculty if I want to.How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
require('config.php');
include('auth.php');
$query = "SELECT name, faculty_id FROM faculty ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="/admin/"><< Go back</a>
<br><br>
<form action="/admin/departments/" method="post">
    <select name="faculties">
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['faculty_id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['save_department'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO department (name) VALUES ('" . $_POST["department_name"] . "')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
$query = "SELECT name, faculty_id, department_ID FROM department ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
<br><br>
<form action="/admin/departments/" method="post">
    <select name="departments">
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['department_ID'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input name="department_name" type="text" required="required"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="save_department">Add Department</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please else with if condition or make query dynamically as:

```
 $query = '';
    if (isset($_POST['save_department'])) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO department (name) VALUES ('" . 
   $_POST["department_name"] . "')";

    }else{
        $query = "SELECT name, faculty_id, department_ID FROM department ORDER BY name ASC";

        }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: Please check $_POST["department_name"] should $_POST["name"] as I am seeing in your code.

Comment: please read my question carefully. It doesnt get added because I need to bind it to a foreign key of one of my faculties ('faculty_id'). That's what I need to do.

Comment: I think should use ajax for that.

Comment: Im sure its not that hard to achive it without ajax. I am just new to it.

Comment: Please see this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185712/how-to-use-ajax-to-populate-state-list-depending-on-country-list

Comment: I do not want to use jQuery.

Comment: okay, How will you populate data in second dropdown when you select falculty?

Comment: by fetching data from the database based on the faculty id,which is the foreign key