# datalist country select for state to show

Tags: php, ajax, datalist

Hey Guy i just needed some help I'm working on a datalist tag with a input type text thou it has `list="id of the input"` and there is some location for country and when you click on it, it will let you select a state in the country here a example [How to use AJAX to populate state list depending on Country list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185712/how-to-use-ajax-to-populate-state-list-depending-on-country-list)  but i want it in a datalist not a select tag.

```
            <div id="Posting-Body-Country">
                <div id="Posting-Body-Country-Head">Country</div>
                <input id="Posting-Body-Country-Input"
                    type="text"
                    name="Location Country"
                    list="Posting-Body-Country-Select">
                <datalist   id="Posting-Body-Country-Select" >
                 <option value="United States">United States</option>
                 <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                 <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                 <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                 <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                 <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                 <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                 <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                 <option value="Antigua & Barbuda">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
                 <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                 <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                 <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                 <option value="Australia">Australia</option>//there still more for countrys
                </datalist>
            </div>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("datalist.Posting-Body-Country-Select").change(function(){
                                    var selectedCountry = $(".Posting-Body-Country-Select option:selected").val();
                                    $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "php-SM-Tag-TravelLocation-CFuction.php",
                                            data: { country : selectedCountry }
                                    }).done(function(data){
                                            $("#Posting-Body-State-Select").html(data);
                                    });
                            });
                    });
                </script>
                <datalist id="Posting-Body-State-Select">
                    <option value="AR">

                    <option value="More...!">
                </datalist>
```

php-SM-Tag-TravelLocation-CFuction.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["country"])){
    // Capture selected country
    $country = $_POST["country"];

    // Define country and city array
    $countryArr = array(

                    //Africa
                    "Algeria" => array("Algiers", "Adrar", "Ain Defla", "Ain Temouchent", "Alger", "Annaba", "Batna", "Bechar", "Bejaia", "Biskra", "Blida", "Bordj Bou Arreridj", "Bouira", "Boumerdes", "Chlef", "Constantine", "Djelfa", "El Bayadh", "El Oued", "El Tarf", "Ghardaia", "Guelma", "Illizi", "Jijel", "Khenchela", "Laghouat", "Mascara", "Medea", "Mila", "Mostaganem", "M\\'Sila", "Naama", "Oran", "Ouargla", "Oum el Bouaghi", "Relizane", "Saida", "Setif", "Sidi Bel Abbes", "Skikda", "Souk Ahras", "Tamanghasset", "Tebessa", "Tiaret", "Tindouf", "Tipaza", "Tissemsilt", "Tizi Ouzou", "Tlemcen")

                );

    // Display city dropdown based on country name
    if($country !== 'Select'){
        echo "<datalist id='Posting-Body-State-Select'>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
            echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</datalist>";
    }
}
```

There is more but there is to much

Comment: what doesn't work here ?

Comment: when you select a country from the list it dont show to state list

Comment: Your selector is wrong this `$("datalist.Posting-Body-Country-Select").change(function(){` should be `$("#Posting-Body-Country-Input").change(function() {` and and simply get value using `var selectedCountry =$(this).val()`

Comment: OH thanks for that!!